# Ado.net entity framework installation on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I have Visual studio 2008 professional edition but it does not have a template for ado.net entity data model.

I have tried downloading a separate file for `Ado.net entity framework 3.5` but it failed to complete the installation because it was for a beta version.

Could someone please advise on how to find/install the missing templates?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986) should have this template installed. Have you installed [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986)?

Also make sure your project is targeting .NET 3.5